# Can a key-value store and a relational table be converted to each other?

Tags: relational-database, key-value-store, google-cloud-spanner

1. Can a key-value store be converted into a relational table, where
   there are just two columns, with  the primary key of the table being the "key" of the key-value store?
2. Can a relational table be converted into a key-value store, where
   the key is the primary key, and the value is the other columns in
   the table?
3. For example, Spanner is a columnary database. From
   https://research.google.com/archive/spanner-osdi2012.pdf, Why can
   Spanner be considered as a key-value store, not relational? I don't
   quite understand "rows must have names. More precisely, every table
   is required to have an ordered set of one or more primary-key columns"

   > **Spanner’s data model is not purely relational**, in that **rows must have
   >   names**. More precisely, every table is required to have an ordered
   >   set of one or more primary-key columns. This requirement is where
   >   **Spanner still looks like a key-value store**: the primary keys form the
   >   name for a row, and each table defines a mapping from the primary-key
   >   columns to the non-primary-key columns. A row has existence only if
   >   some value (even if it is NULL) is defined for the row’s keys.
   >   Imposing this structure is useful because it lets applications
   >   control data locality through their choices of keys.

Comment: If you can't answer the first 2 questions you should read a textbook introduction to information modeling, database design & the relational model and/or to key-value stores. Let alone explaining 3. The relational model data structure is entirely a collection of relation variables holding sets of rows of columns of values. It's not clear what the quote is trying to say, since a relational row is unique in a table so does have a subrow acting as "name" although any other structure is non-relational. SQL has duplicate rows, they might think "relational" means "SQL".

Comment: Thanks. "a relational row is unique in a table". Do you think that the answers to the first two questions are both yes?

Comment: The first two questions are well defined. As far as I know, my guess to the first two questions are both yes.

Comment: "KV" has no single definite meaning. What is "can be converted"? Can your suggested result designs be reasonably *used*? So 1 & 2 are unclear. And is your notion of KV the same as in the paper/quote?The quote is too unclear for us know what it says. It seems to be a summary of stuff from the contaning exposition so read that, which should also clarify their use of "relational" & "key-value". PS To be on-topic ask a specific question re some place you are stuck. This is unclear (since your use of KV & the quote are unclear) & if clarified would be too broad. And it's not researched. [ask]

Comment: @philipxy  You could use the definitions which are the most common or accurate to your knowledge

Comment: You are writing the post. If you don't know what the words mean you are not asking a question. If you are asking for answers covering various general meanings that's too broad. If you can't give specific cases for word meanings that's unrearched. If you don't give specific justified mapping solutions for specific meanings that's unclear & no effort. Etc etc. Ask a specific question about being stuck in a specific situation.

Comment: I wrote it, but I don't claim what I know is correct

Comment: From a quick look at that paper, that is all they say about their "data model" so it is unclear about what they mean by either "relational" (we can guess they mean some kind of non-relational SQL bag of rows involving NULLs) or "key-value" (we can guess they just mean a general notion of a unique key with associated value.) So there's no answering 3. They're not so clear re Spanner either. Apparently one of their tables has one set of columns forming a PK & a set of other columns. You can look for other presentations & documentation that might seem to come from the same place re those 2 terms.

Answer (score 1):

Re:3, The paper's assertion is that Spanner's data model cannot be considered 'Relational' in the strictest sense of the word because the Relational model has no notion of row names (i.e. primary keys). In the [Relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model), a Relation is defined as a set of n-ary tuples. That means that a relation by definition cannot have duplicate rows and does not order its rows (a set cannot have duplicate elements and does not define any order between its elements), Therefore, in the Relational data model, a row name aka 'primary key' is not needed to identify a row (the entire row is basically a primary key) whereas Spanner requires every table(an RDBMS's approximation to the theoretical concept of a 'relation') to either have a unique primary key or have only a single row.

The requirement of having a 'row name' or 'key' is characteristic of a key-value store and therefore in that sense, Spanner can be thought of as a key-value store.

Comment: The RM does have a notion of identifying row names, namely superkeys, which include CKs, which include PKs. Moreover, KV stores have exactly the same notion of names since a K is the analogue of a superkey. Contrary to what you write. There are senses in which "row name" is non-relational but such senses are also non-KV. Anyway it's not clear what the article means by "relational" or "KV" or "row name" or what it is saying about Spanner tables. PS What do you mean, "the Relational model has no notion of row names (i.e. primary keys)"? "PK" is a RM term.

Comment: I meant that the mathematical concept of a 'relation' doesn't depend on the concept of a 'key' (assuming that that's what the author means by a 'row name'). If you consider 'Relational Model' to include the concept of a 'relation' + FDs, then yes the statement 'no notion of primary keys' is incorrect.

Comment: But if you just talk about the concept of a 'relation', then while you can always *define* a key on a relation as a minimal set of attributes that functionally determines any element in that set, the existence of the relation doesn't depend on the key. In the context of an RDBMS (the application implementing the theoretical relational model) that basically means that you can have a table without any primary key columns (database systems such as postgresql allow it), but you can't have that in Spanner.

Comment: Every relation has all its columns as supekey hence has that as a "name" for a row. Your post is not clear & whatever you are trying to say, "the Relational model has no notion of row names" is wrong & the quote & paper are not clear. Sure, they're trying to say something like Spanner's structure can be taken as a special case of a relational design like having K & V columns. But nothing beyond that is clear including what they think "relational" means. The quote is a mess & the paper is poor.